# Deserializing FileInfo object C# with BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, fileinfo, binaryformatter

These are the 2 functions that I use to deserialize, one from a networkStream and the other from a file stream

```
public static FileInfo recMetaSerialized(Socket s)
    {
        FileInfo o = null;
        try {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            NetworkStream stm = new NetworkStream(s);
            o = (FileInfo)bf.Deserialize(stm);
            Console.WriteLine("File info received recMetaSerialized: " + o.FullName + o.LastWriteTime);
            return o;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in deserialization from the network. " +e.Message + e.StackTrace);
        }
        return null;
    }


public static FileInfo readMetaSerialized(string file)
    {
        FileInfo o = null;
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stm = new FileStream(file,FileMode.Open);
            o = (FileInfo)bf.Deserialize(stm);
            Console.WriteLine("File info received readMetaSerialized : " + o.FullName + o.LastWriteTime);
            return o;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in deserialization from the file. " + e.Message + e.StackTrace);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I get some errors, as the FullName attribute of the FileInfo is correctly printed out, whereas LastWriteTime is wrong. In the functions that serialize the object the attributes are correctly serialized.

```
public static void saveMetaSerialized(string file, FileInfo obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new Exception("Error! File info obj is null!");
        Console.WriteLine("File info received saveMetaSerialized: " + obj.FullName + obj.LastWriteTime);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        try {
            using (FileStream ms = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
            {
                bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

            }
        }            
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in file ser of file {0} : {1}", obj.Name, e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Serialization over the net of file {0} completed.", obj.Name);
    }

public static void sendMetaSerialized(Socket s, string file)
    {

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
        Console.WriteLine("File info received sendMetaSerialized: " + fi.FullName + fi.LastWriteTime);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        try {
            bf.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
            NetworkStream stm = new NetworkStream(s);
            bf.Serialize(stm, fi);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in net ser of file {0} : {1}", fi.Name, e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Serialization over the net of file {0} completed.", fi.Name);
    }
```

Comment: By design, FileInfo will return the *current* attributes of the file.   It will also fail if the file is not present after you deserialized it.  You need to consider creating your own class to store the file properties if this behavior is undesirable.

Comment: Ok thank you! And How can i send an object of my class through a network strem without getting a serialization error? I mean, for security reason C# doesn't allow to deserialize an object without the correct assembly and I don't know how to import it.

Comment: In the serialize function add following : ms.Flush(); and ms.Close();  I suspect not all the data at the end of the file is not properly being written.

Comment: @Hans Passant - the class FileSystemInfo has the same behaviour of FileInfo?

Comment: Yes, LastWriteTime is in fact implemented by FileSystemInfo.

Comment: All write methods are buffered and without the flush there is no guarantee that data in the buffer is actually written to the file.